# After updating to 1.9.3 images in fronted not loading from cache

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, product-images

Upgraded Magento from 1.8.0.1 to latest 1.9.3. and all seemed to be fine. The image uploader was broken but managed to fix that by reading the files for the older flash uploader. So basically can add images to products and it works. However, there is some problem with the cache and images on frontend is slowly disappearing. They are loaded from media/catalog/product/cache/etc... but the image is not there. Seems as the caching of images is broken or something. Found several threads on the subject but none with this particular issue. Any ideas how to solve it?

EDIT: Some new info. Also upgraded php on the server from 5.4 to 5.6 and it seems as magento is rebuilding cache fine but only for png images. My assumption is that php_gd is not set to work with jpg. How do activate that?

Comment: does your site implement CDN?

Comment: Hey, yes it uses cloudflare

Comment: are the images cached by CDN?

Comment: Hey, no have but the CDN in development mode to make it not cache the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be solved by clearing the image cache so Magento builds it up again, you can do this in Cache Management:
[image]

Comment: Have tried this several time but no luck, unfortunately. The cache seems to bot rebuild itself or something.

Answer (score 0):

Please click on flush cache and before that make sure your memory limit is at least 512M

Comment: Have tried this but didn't work. Set the php max file upload size to 512M in the .htaccess file. Have checked other files like index.php and php.ini for other references to the memory limit but couldn't find it anywhere else than in the htacess. Is there any way to check if it is actually set to 512M?

Comment: use <?php phpinfo(); ?>