# Problem with product image cache after upgrade

Tags: cache, product-images, upgrade, ce-1.8.1.0, magento-1.9.3.2

I'm new to Magento. I have just upgraded from 1.8.1.0 to 1.9.3.2. Something with the product image cache is not working. On my checkout page I get a long list of `404 Not Found` errors for cached product images. See image below for more details. I see no errors in Apache error log, nor in `var/log/system.log`. What can I do? I have emptied the image cache. Can I somehow trigger a manual rebuild for the image cache?

I followed all suggestions from [Magento not rebuilding product image cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074824/magento-not-rebuilding-product-image-cache) but none solved the problem.

If it's relevant, Magento's cron job is currently not running on this machine since it is a development environment. Could that cause the problem? Maybe the image cache is triggered by a cron job?

A look in the requested folder shows that the `500x500` directory is missing:

```
$ ls media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/
38x  75x
```

A screenshot from my browser console when visiting the checkout page:

[image: A lot of 404 Not Found messages on checkout page]

**Edit 1**

The web server has all permissions to the `cache` directory in `media/catalog/product` and its sub directories:

```
$ ll media/catalog/product/
...
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data  www-data 4096 May 24 09:47 cache
$ find media/catalog/product/cache/ -maxdepth 2 -ls
    5898242    4 drwxrwxrwx   3 www-data www-data     4096 May 24 09:47 media/catalog/product/cache/
    5898243    4 drwxrwxrwx   5 www-data www-data     4096 May 24 09:55 media/catalog/product/cache/1
    5898289    4 drwxrwxrwx   4 www-data www-data     4096 May 24 09:47 media/catalog/product/cache/1/image
    5900914    4 drwxrwxrwx   3 www-data www-data     4096 May 24 09:55 media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image
    5898271    4 drwxrwxrwx   4 www-data www-data     4096 May 24 09:47 media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail
```

**Edit 2**

[After updating to 1.9.3 images in fronted not loading from cache](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172777/after-updating-to-1-9-3-images-in-fronted-not-loading-from-cache) describes the same problem, but no solution was provided and I cannot comment on the question since my current reputation is too low.

**Edit 3**

The original images seems to be in place. I managed to find the URL to the original images by looking at the URL for the cached images.